useradd -D command is not reflecting the CREATE_HOME=no setting from /etc/default/useradd
I am experimenting my first linux commands with CentOS Linux release 7.9 and I stumbled upon a strange behavior.
My goal was to add a new user to my linux, but not create home directory for it initially.
I went ahead:
sudo useradd user1 

I noticed that a new home directory was created for the user1 regardless of the -m option not provided.
I checked the /etc/default/useradd and I found no configuration explicitly for creating home directory there:
~ cat /etc/default/useradd 
# useradd defaults file
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes

then I investigate the /etc/login.defs, and sure enough i saw the a CREATE_HOME yes
 ~ cat /etc/login.defs 
... 

#
# If useradd should create home directories for users by default
# On RH systems, we do. This option is overridden with the -m flag on
# useradd command line.
#
CREATE_HOME     yes

To override this behavior, I added the override config to the /etc/default/useradd as following: CREATE_HOME=no
but apparently, the config is not reflected in the useradd command. because user is created with home directory by default and also, useradd command is not respecting my new config
~ useradd -D 
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes

Any idea?

The man page of useradd does not mention that one can override CREATE_HOME in /etc/default/useradd.
